# Scala Spark arrays combination without duplicate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, combinations

***This can be useful for the Apriori Algorithm***

I have 2 arrays :

```
scala> a.take(3)
res1: Array[String] = Array(cat, dog, bird)
scala> b.take(3)
res2: Array[String] = Array(cat, dog, bird)
```

How can I do all the pairs combinations without duplicate pairs ?
so for example :

with > `(cat,dog)` 
but not with the duplicate  > `(dog, cat)`

```
scala> for (a_ <- a; b_ <-b) yield (a_, b_)     
<console>:35: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]
required: TraversableOnce[?]
```

finally, I would only like to have :

```
    (cat, dog)
    (cat, bird)
    (dog, bird)
```

Comment: Please include the code as text instead of images

Comment: Please post some code that you have written yourself as an attempt at a solution

Comment: You  can find solution [here](https://i.imgur.com/dsBsmbR.png)

Comment: While [this](https://i.imgur.com/7ZJXhD9.png) can be useful too

Comment: @Odomontois - perhaps it's better if we keep the questions and answers as text, and both within SO. For one thing, it makes them searchable

Comment: Odomontois, I agree ! but you have (1,2) and (2,1) in your first example

Comment: "have 2 arrays " Your first code fragment has `Array`,. The error message says `RDD`. The difference matters. Which is it?

Comment: are there any duplicates in either array or are all elements distinct?

Comment: can we assume the elements can be ordered? Then generate all combinations with `cartesian`, map over them to generate a key that is (smaller-of-pair, bigger-of-pair), reduceByKey and just pick the first value each time. map to take the values only. Tada! It wll be slow (buit then it has to be - to know when to discard an element you have to see if you've got it or its swapped alternate already and that's expensive)

Comment: have you a example code ? please

Comment: val pairs = a.cartesian(b).filter({case (x,y)=> (x,y) != (y,x)}).map({ case (x,y)    if x>y => (y,x) }) then I don't understand your "reduceByKey"

Comment: The `reduceByKey` is just to discard all but one of the entries that have the same key. You don't care which one presumably. Or you could use `groupByKey`and then `map` to discard all but one element of the values...

Answer (score 1):

We use the filter x < y, then we dont need to order, because that will exclude all the incorrect pairs.

Finally the answer is:

```
    val combinations = a.cartesian(b).filter{case(x,y) => x < y}
```

Comment: Pretty much sure, arrays haven't the `cartesian` operations defined in the standard implicit enrichments

Comment: @Odomontois, it's an RDD, despite the example code from the OP. See the error message.